# Can't figure out how to properly output my data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a relative novice at python but yet, somehow managed to build a scraper for Instagram. I now want to take this one step further and output the 5 most commonly used hashtags from an IG profile into my CSV output file.

**Current output:**

I've managed to isolate the 5 most commonly used hashtags, but I get this result in my csv:

> [('#striveforgreatness', 3), ('#jamesgang', 3), ('#thekidfromakron',
>   2), ('#togetherwecanchangetheworld', 1), ('#halloweenchronicles', 1)]

[image: csv output]

**Desired output:**

What I'm looking to end up with in the end is having 5 columns at the end of my .CSV outputting the X-th most commonly used value.

So something in the lines of this:

[image: desired output]

I've Googled for a while and managed to isolate them separately, but I always end up with '('#thekidfromakron', 2)' as an output. I seem to be missing some part of the puzzle :(.

Here is what I'm working with at the moment:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re
import time
from collections import Counter
ts = time.gmtime()


def get_csv_header(top_numb):
        fieldnames = ['USER','MEDIA COUNT','FOLLOWERCOUNT','TOTAL LIKES','TOTAL COMMENTS','ER','ER IN %', 'BIO', 'ALL CAPTION TEXT','HASHTAGS COUNTED','MOST COMMON HASHTAGS']
        return fieldnames


def write_csv_header(filename, headers):
        with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as f_out:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=headers)
            writer.writeheader()
        return

def read_user_name(t_file):
        with open(t_file) as f:
            user_list = f.read().splitlines()
        return user_list
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # HERE YOU CAN SPECIFY YOUR USERLIST FILE NAME,
    # Which contains a list of usernames's BY DEFAULT <current working directory>/userlist.txt
    USER_FILE = 'userlist.txt'

    # HERE YOU CAN SPECIFY YOUR DATA FILE NAME, BY DEFAULT (data.csv)', Where your final result stays
    DATA_FILE = 'users_with_er.csv'
    MAX_POST = 12  # MAX POST

    print('Starting the engagement calculations... Please wait until it finishes!')


    users = read_user_name(USER_FILE)
    """ Writing data to csv file """
    csv_headers = get_csv_header(MAX_POST)
    write_csv_header(DATA_FILE, csv_headers)

    for user  in users:

        post_info = {'USER': user}
        url = 'https://www.instagram.com/' + user + '/'

        #for troubleshooting, un-comment the next two lines:
        #print(user)
        #print(url)

        try: 
            r = requests.get(url)
            if r.status_code != 200: 
                print(timestamp,' user {0} not found or page unavailable! Skipping...'.format(user))
                continue
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
            scripts = soup.find_all('script', type="text/javascript", text=re.compile('window._sharedData'))
            stringified_json = scripts[0].get_text().replace('window._sharedData = ', '')[:-1]

            j = json.loads(stringified_json)['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]
            timestamp = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", ts)
        except ValueError:
            print(timestamp,'ValueError for username {0}...Skipping...'.format(user))
            continue
        except IndexError as error:
        # Output expected IndexErrors.
            print(timestamp, error)
            continue
        if j['graphql']['user']['edge_followed_by']['count'] <=0:
            print(timestamp,'user {0} has no followers! Skipping...'.format(user))
            continue
        if j['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['count'] <12:
            print(timestamp,'user {0} has less than 12 posts! Skipping...'.format(user))
            continue
        if j['graphql']['user']['is_private'] is True:
            print(timestamp,'user {0} has a private profile! Skipping...'.format(user))
            continue
        media_count = j['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['count']
        accountname = j['graphql']['user']['username']
        followercount = j['graphql']['user']['edge_followed_by']['count']
        bio = j['graphql']['user']['biography']
        i = 0
        total_likes = 0
        total_comments = 0
        all_captiontext = ''
        while i <= 11: 
                total_likes += j['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['edges'][i]['node']['edge_liked_by']['count']
                total_comments += j['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['edges'][i]['node']['edge_media_to_comment']['count']
                captions = j['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['edges'][i]['node']['edge_media_to_caption']
                caption_detail = captions['edges'][0]['node']['text']
                all_captiontext += caption_detail
                i += 1
        engagement_rate_percentage = '{0:.4f}'.format((((total_likes + total_comments) / followercount)/12)*100) + '%'
        engagement_rate = (((total_likes + total_comments) / followercount)/12*100)

        #isolate and count hashtags
        hashtags = re.findall(r'#\w*', all_captiontext)
        hashtags_counted = Counter(hashtags)
        most_common = hashtags_counted.most_common(5)

        with open('users_with_er.csv', 'a', newline='',  encoding='utf-8') as data_out:

            print(timestamp,'Writing Data for user {0}...'.format(user))            
            post_info["USER"] = accountname
            post_info["FOLLOWERCOUNT"] = followercount
            post_info["MEDIA COUNT"] = media_count
            post_info["TOTAL LIKES"] = total_likes
            post_info["TOTAL COMMENTS"] = total_comments
            post_info["ER"] = engagement_rate
            post_info["ER IN %"] = engagement_rate_percentage
            post_info["BIO"] = bio
            post_info["ALL CAPTION TEXT"] = all_captiontext
            post_info["HASHTAGS COUNTED"] = hashtags_counted
            csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(data_out, fieldnames=csv_headers)
            csv_writer.writerow(post_info)

""" Done with the script """
print('ALL DONE !!!! ')
```

The code that goes before this simply scrapes the webpage, and compiles all the captions from the last 12 posts into "all_captiontext".

Any help to solve this (probably simple) issue would be greatly appreciated as I've been struggling with this for days (again, I'm a noob :') ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace line

```
post_info["MOST COMMON HASHTAGS"] = most_common
```

with:

```
for i, counter_tuple in enumerate(most_common):
  tag_name = counter_tuple[0].replace('#','')
  label = "Top %d" % (i + 1)
  post_info[label] = tag_name
```

There's also a bit of code missing. For example, your code doesn't include `csv_headers` variable, which I suppose would be

```
csv_headers = post_info.keys()
```

It also seems that you're opening a file to write just one row. I don't think that's intended, so what you would like to do is to collect the results into a list of dictionaries. A cleaner solution would be to use pandas' dataframe, which you can [output straight into a csv file](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the feedback, your solution is getting me close but I'm getting a few errors related to the creation of the columns. 

I have actually included my full code now, since excluding parts just makes it unclear as to how it's all working together. The code itself is a collection of other, existing codes I found online. So I'm quite sure there are unnecessary or inefficient bits in there :).

Comment: Yeah there's a lot of messiness in the code so after you refactor your code properly I'm sure you'll get your errors fixed. I suggest looking into some software design guide or getting a mentor to look into your coding practices. :)

Comment: With your suggested code and some rework to make it fit into my mess I was able to work it out! Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

most_common being the output of the call to hashtags_counted.most_common, I had a look at the doc here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common

Output if formatted the following : `[(key, value), (key, value), ...]` and ordered in decreasing importance of number of occurences.

Hence, to get only the name and not the number of occurence, you should replace:

```
post_info["MOST COMMON HASHTAGS"] = most_common
```

by

```
post_info["MOST COMMON HASHTAGS"] = [x[0] for x in most_common]
```

You have a list of tuple. This statement builds on the fly the list of the first element of each tuple, keeping the sorting order.